How to Fail a Polling Step in Locust on Timeout and Measure Total Time
I have a Locust test that executes a flow of steps:
@task
def execute_tasks():
   test = TestFlow(self.client)
   test.step1()
   test.step2()
   ...

One of the steps involves polling for a status:
def test4(self, timeout_seconds=420, interval_seconds=5):
    start = time.time()
    is_done = False
    while not is_done and time.time() - start < timeout_seconds:
        time.sleep(interval_seconds)
        response = self.client.get("url", name="wait_for_test")
        test_status = response.json()
        is_done = test_status["status"] == "COMPLETED"

    if not is_done:
        raise Exception("Polling timed out!")

Questions:

How do I mark this step as failed in Locust if it times out (instead
of just raising an exception)?

How can I measure the total polling duration (from the start of
polling until a "COMPLETED" status is received) rather than just
tracking individual GET requests?



You can invoke the failure() method of the returned response.
This requires the get function to pass parameter catch_response set to True and be wrapped in a with statement:
with self.client.get("url", name="wait_for_test", catch_response=True) as response:
  response.failure("Polling timed out!")

Documentation can be found here:
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#manually-controlling-if-a-request-should-be-considered-successful-or-a-failure
